# Check weekdays from file with current weekday in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want a Skript that checks if the current weekday is in a file in german with multiple weekdays.

I can just ckeck in i enter the Weekdays directly in a variable like this:

```
# Pfad zur Datei
$dateiPfad = "D:\Scriptz\RunDay.txt"

# Gesuchtes Wort
$gesuchtesWort = "Mittwoch"

# Lese die Wörter aus der Datei
$inhalt = Get-Content -Path $dateiPfad
$woerterListe = $inhalt -split ','

# Überprüfe, ob das gesuchte Wort in der Liste ist
if ($woerterListe -contains $gesuchtesWort) {
    Write-Host "Das Wort '$gesuchtesWort' wurde in der Datei gefunden."
} else {
    Write-Host "Das Wort '$gesuchtesWort' wurde nicht in der Datei gefunden."
}
```

but if i use something like this:

```
#get german weekday
$deutscheKultur = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo "de-DE"
$heute = Get-Date
$deutscherWochentag = $heute.ToString("dddd", $deutscheKultur)

#test if var is correct until now
Write-Host "Der heutige Wochentag ist: $deutscherWochentag"


#Weekday file path
$dateiPfad = "D:\Scriptz\RunDay.txt"

# read content of file and split
$wochentagAusDatei = Get-Content -Path $dateiPfad
$wochentageListe = $wochentageInDatei -split ','


#testcomparison
if ($wochentageListe -contains $wochentagAusDatei) {
    # Führen Sie hier Ihr Skript oder Ihre Befehle aus
    Write-Host "Heute ist $wochentagAusDatei. Das Skript wird ausgeführt."
} else {
    Write-Host "Heute ist nicht $wochentagAusDatei. Das Skript wird nicht ausgeführt."
}
```

the output i get is the german weekdav is getting correct,
but here it seems it cant use if ($wochentageListe -contains $wochentagAusDatei) here both vars n ot with each other.

I found something, that the weekdays from the file has to be converted into get date fornmat, but i couldnt find an example how i could convert a list of weekdays - just single dates.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$wochentagAusDatei` is the content of your file and `$wochentageListe` is that same content but split by `,` in your second example. This doesnt make sense. Seems you have confused variables here?

Comment: Yeah youre right - i made a mistake when i fused the regular code with the code with the function to see if there are more than just a day.
and somehow i see chatgpt has done some weird coding

Answer (score 1):

Use the DayOfWeek property:

```
(Get-Date).DayOfWeek
```

Comment: This works well if the desired culture is the current culture. No ability to specify a different culture.

Answer (score 1):

```
with Italian variable names. Because.

# Decide on what language you are going to search.
# Potentially superfluous, it's better if is there as it can be easily recycled by different users with different language settings
$cultura = 'de-DE'

# File location
$PosizioneDelDocumento = 'D:\Scriptz\RunDay.txt'
# Get the content of the file
$ContenutoDelDocumento = Get-Content $PosizioneDelDocumento
# Split the content by ',' and make a Array out of it
$MatriceDelContenuto = $ContenutoDelDocumento -split ','

# Get today's Day Name in the language previously decided.
# one could remove the $cultura so it would use the current scope culture, but see above 
$ParolaRicercata = $(Get-Date).ToString('dddd', (Get-Culture $cultura))

# check if the name is inside the array
if ( $ParolaRicercata -iin $MatriceDelContenuto) {
    # if yes, write this
    Write-Host "Das Wort '$ParolaRicercata' wurde in der Datei gefunden."
}
else {
    # if no, write this
    Write-Host "Das Wort '$ParolaRicercata' wurde nicht in der Datei gefunden."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it now thanks to @Santiago Squarzon - I translated it to English so if it's easier to understand:

```
#get german weekday
$gercultinf = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo "de-DE"
$today = Get-Date
$currentweekdayger = $today.ToString("dddd", $gercultinf)

#test if var is correct until now
Write-Host "$currentweekdayger"


#Weekday file path
$flepath = "D:\Scriptz\RunDay.txt"
# read content of file and split
$weekdaysfrmfile = Get-Content -Path $flepath
$weekdaylist = $weekdaysfrmfile -split ','


#testcomparison
if ($weekdaylist -contains $currentweekdayger) {
    Write-Host "today ist $currentweekdayger and its in the file"
} else {
    Write-Host "today ist $currentweekdayger and its not mentioned in the file so nothing will happen"
}
```